# viewControllerAfterViewController: does not get called with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I ran into a quite strange behavior of UIPageViewController.

I'm using UIPageViewController to display a set of ViewControllers, so I conform to UIPageViewControllerDataSource protocol, and implemented the following method:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(NHBufferRoomViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Got here!!");
    NSInteger newIndex = [_imageManager currentImageIdx] + 1;
    if (newIndex >= [_imageManager count]) return nil;

    NSLog(@"%d", newIndex);
    NHBufferRoomViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BufferRoom"];
    [controller updateImageAtIndex:newIndex];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kCurrentImageIndex object:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:newIndex]];
    return controller;
}
```

But when I swipe the page view controller, sometimes, the view controller did move to the next page, but the `NSLog(@"Got here!!");` does not get called until I swipe again, this is quite strange. As far as I can understand, the page view controller should call this method when it needs to display a new page, right? But why the method is not called?

I'm setting the transition type to scroll by the way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already solve this problem? I'm facing the same behavior and don't have any solution...

Comment: Same here. Especially when you swipe completely from the right to the left the next page will be shown, but the method will not be called.
Moving the image a bit back and forward will trigger the call. Strange...

Comment: @eftokay83, sadly, no. I gave up on this one..

Comment: did you solved this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.
Its problem apple's api.

Solution : Dont go for UIPageViewController, rather implement it by UIScrollView with pagination